# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

```
    ...
    ...
    ...

            try
            {
                string Tags_collect;

                SqlDataReader Data1 = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                Data1.Read();
                lbl_q_title.Text = Data1["subject"].ToString();

               Data1.NextResult();


               while (Data1.Read())
               {
                   Tags_collect = Data1.GetString(0);
                   Tags_collect= Tags_collect+ Tags_collect;
               }

               lbl_tags.Text = Tags_collect;
    .....
    ....

   ....
```

not sure why i get this error
what do i miss?

Comment: Tags_collect is an unassigned local variable. The execution may never enter the while block.

Comment: How about telling us where the compiler specifically complains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first time you assign to `Tags_collect` is inside the `while (Data1.Read())` loop, which is not guaranteed to ever execute.

Fix this by initializing the variable when it's declared:

```
string Tags_collect = string.Empty;
```

Better yet, use a `StringBuilder` instead of relying on repeated concatenations:

```
StringBuilder tags = new StringBuilder();
// ...
while (Data1.Read())
{
    string tag = Data1.GetString(0);
    sb.Append(tag);
    sb.Append(",");  // Separator
}
lbl_tags.Text = tags.ToString();
```

Concatenating a string to itself in a loop is very inefficient because strings are immutable, so each concatenation creates a brand-new instance.  Using a `StringBuilder` prevents this by using a single buffer.

Comment: +1  Note to @Bob, everything after "better yet" can be ignored until you feel like tackling performance/memory usage issues. It's important info, but not related to your "unassigned variable" problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because if `Data1.Read()` returns false at the beginning `Tags_collect` is not assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to take into account the possibility that `Data1.Read()` in the while loop condition may never return true. If that happens then Tags_collect is never initialized, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your reader in a while loop like this small sample:

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

```
    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            reader[0], reader[1]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string Tags_collect=string.empty;
```